# Dropdown menu doesn't get visible when hover over button

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu

I've finished a dropdown menu for a button i've created. Here is the [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/vixfemcg)

The only problem is in fact that the dropdown menu doesn't get visible when I hover my mouse over the button.

I've added `display: block` and `display:none` in the correct CSS i believe and i can't figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp all your code in a div tag, and add the hover to it

```
<div class="language-icon-wrapper">    
    <a class="language-icon" href="#" alt="choose-your-language">Language</a> 
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>

    <div class="language-dropdown">
        <!--- your list here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use `opacity:1` and `display:block` to show a hidden element, or only display none/block, you can animate the opacity after you change the display rule.

**Css**

```
.language-icon-wrapper:hover .language-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  display:block;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MX4eG/1/)

First to notice is that this trick only works when you hover a parent and the element that you want to make visible is a child of the hovered element, in your case you have the anchor tag as sibling of the list that you want to show, so you should place the dropdown menu inside your element, but as second thing to notice is that it won't work with all tags, i'm not quite sure why, but some inline elements won't work for this, even if you set its display property to block, i guess that maybe browsers won't allow this since is not semantically correct to place a submenu inside an anchor tag. Even though i said inline, i know it works with span tags, so its probably about the semantic.

As an advice, for menus and submenus use ul and li tags, gl

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo CSSDesk](http://cssdeck.com/labs/lew7wxyz)

Use `display:none` and `display:block` to solve this issue.

#### CSS

```
.language-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.language-icon-wrapper:hover .language-dropdown {
  display:block;
}
```